# Story about a girl who discovers she lives in an "exhibition" and manages to escape to Indianapolis/Minneapolis

Tags: story-identification, books, dystopia

If I recall correctly, the story describes life on the American frontier, but the characters soon realise there's a world outside and that they're essentially living in an exhibition. The characters then escape and I am 99% sure that the area they escape to the "real world" and discover the truth is either: Indianapolis or Minneapolis - it definitely ends in -polis. I read this in about 2000, but no idea when it was published!

This is a book. People say it sounds similar to *Westworld* and it is very similar, but they are humans not robots.

I may be entirely wrong but I believe that the characters discover that they are in this exhibition because they discover some "limits" to their world maybe like the glass panel or something. I also think there is some requirement for the girl to *go* somewhere outside of the exhibition maybe for medical reasons but honestly I am not sure that this is true or if I'm making things up.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the plot of the *Westworld* TV show, though that's obviously not the answer since it's from about 2016.

Comment: Thanks @TheLethalCarrot I saw your answer and it was great - if you see the wiki article it says the publishers noted a strong similarity between the book and the film https://www.theguardian.com/film/2004/aug/10/news1

Comment: @opr No wonder it reminded me of it then! Deleted the answer when I realised you were looking for a book though but glad you found it.

Comment: Cf Piers Anthony's "Race Against Time", 1973

Comment: This sounds like the YA *Truman Show*.

Comment: @F1Krazy Westworld was originally a series of novels that came out in the 70's

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I found the book! It is called [*Running out of Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_Out_of_Time_(Haddix_novel)) (1995) by Margaret Peterson Haddix.

> Jessie Keyser is a 13-year-old girl from the village of Clifton, Indiana, in the 1840s. During a village-wide outbreak of diphtheria, Jessie's mother reveals it is really 1996, and Clifton Village is a tourist attraction. Also, there are cameras all around watching them, but there are some blind spots. Jessica’s mother takes her to a blind spot for the reveal because all the adults were contracted to not tell the kids. Clifton is a replica of a historical village with the tourists hidden, watching the village's activity by video from under the ground.

Comment: Glad you found it! Note you can accept your own answer in ~48 hours to signify that you have found the answer. Please do so.

Comment: Yes! The masterminds are secretly also trying to test human immunity to diptheria -- that's why the girl's mother sends her out, to get help because they aren't being given modern medicine! I remember being _very troubled_ by this possibility as a kid.